# my first application android

Tags: android

hello i try to use simple application in android but i have many problems ;

i need when i click in button text change in "hh";

my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

my class

```
package com.my.Hello;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HelloActivity extends Activity{
    Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setText("hh");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            button.setText("hh");
        }
        });

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    }
```

i have good resultat in UI but when i click in button not thing happen ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're setting the text to "hh" in the `onCreate()` so clicking it would not change it.

Also, you are calling `setContentView()` twice, so the second time just invalidates everything you've already coded.

Try this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button.setText("hh");
        }
    });
}
```